# iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException Connection error: Connection was dropped (may not be a SQL Anywhere server)

Tags: .net-core, sybase, azure-service-fabric, sqlanywhere

While trying to connect to SQLAnywhere (Sybase) database (C# code) from Azure ServiceFabric:

```
await using var connection = new SAConnection(connectionString);
await connection.OpenAsync();
```

receive iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException

```
Connection error: Connection was dropped (may not be a SQL Anywhere server)
```

Error code is Error 832. [This is generic connection error](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00462.1510/concepts/con_syberror.html): `An error occurred while attempting to establish a connection with the database server, but before attempting to connect to a database. Failure to initialize a communication link during the connection attempt is an example of this error. Creating a debug log file using the LogFile connection parameter may provide more information.`

Locally it works, but does not work from Service Fabric.

Fix ideas tried:

1. Missing driver? Looks like no, Sybase (now SAP) SQLAnywhere requires special driver or client - but locally also works without this driver, just with iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.NETCore nupackage installed
2. Network connection/ firewall problems? Looks like no, database server can be pinged from Service Fabric node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was another traffic protection tool. Although it was possible to telnet the port, still traffic from app was blocked by another tool.

Comment: And another huge problem was - slow speed with new .net core version of this package. Turns out, it cannot handle outgoing parameters well - the defined size of parameter will actually be send out:
```
            var yourOutParameter = new SAParameter("@OutMsg", SADbType.Binary)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                Size = 256000000,
                IsNullable = true
            };
```
So check what is actual message size for your responses, maybe 1 megabyte or even kilobytes are enough, and set size parameter accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue - turned out that whilst standard incoming traffic from the Sybase Server had been whitelisted in our Firewall, encrypted traffic from this had not been.

This meant I could ping and connect with Telnet, but got the same error when trying to log-in with my credentials

*Connection error: Connection was dropped (may not be a SQL Anywhere server)*

Our comms team solved the issue by whitelisted encrypted traffic from the server address as well. They also mentioned it possibly could have been solved we shared a valid security certificate for the encrypted data with their team, but were happy with the first course of action.